# Struts1 - Passing objects between servlets and jsp

Tags: java, struts1

What is the best way to pass objects between servlets and JSP when using Struts1? Help needed.

Comment: A little bit of code to show us what you're trying to pass around and what you've tried might help.  What's "best" is often a matter of opinion and debate until you get down to details.

Comment: I have 5 different lists. And i have populated them in action and want to pass them to jsp. What is the best way?

P.S. I dont have any action form assigned with the action.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the objects in your `ActionForm` and define getters for them, or put them in request attributes directly.

In the JSP, use `${myActionForm.myObject}` of `${myAttributeName}` (respectively) to get the object.

Comment: If i have 5 different lists to populate in the action form, should i put them in 5 different request atrributes?

Comment: and if i have not associated the action with any action form, then is it recommended way to set this much request Attributes to pass objects to jsp?

Comment: I usually prefer using an ActionForm as a way to store all the needed objects, because it makes it clear that these objects are needed, it avoid name clashes between attributes, and it allows documenting them. I thus always have an ActionForm, even if it's only used to store output data, and no input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Set the object as an attribute on the [session](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) or [request](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29).